# StrictModeDiskReadViolation only gets resolved with AsyncTask, why?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using strict mode for android 3.2 and am getting `StrictModeDiskReadViolation` during `onCreate` in my `Activity`.

I tried to moved the code that does an SQL query to:

- a new `Thread`.
- a new `AsyncTaskLoader`.
- a new `AsynTask`.

The problem is only `AsyncTask` made the Violation dissappear and I'm wondering why the other two methods didn't work?

Here is my code:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Dao<Listino, Integer> dao = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(ListinoActivity.this).getListinoDao();
                    if (dao.countOf() == 1)
                    {
                        long id = dao.queryForAll().get(0).getId();//long non int
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(ListinoActivity.this, ListinoProdottiActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("listino_id", id);
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        ListinoActivity.this.finish();
                        ListinoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MyToast.makeText(ListinoActivity.this, "Errore ottenere i listini", MyToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        };
        asyncTask.execute();

        AsyncTaskLoader async = new AsyncTaskLoader(this) {


            @Override
            public Object loadInBackground() {
                //do stuff, violation still here
                return null;
            }
        };

        async.loadInBackground();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                //do stuff, violation still here

            }
        };
        t.run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not fork a `Thread`. To fork a `Thread`, you call `start()`. You called `run()`, which simply ran your `run()` method on the current thread.

And you did not come even close to using the `Loader` framework properly. The code you have there not only suffers from the same flaw as what you did with your `Thread`, but that is not how you use a `Loader`.

Comment: I think `Thread.run()` needs to be marked deprecated to avoid this problem.  It could be replaced by a protected method that can be overridden, or the entire idea of subclassing `Thread` could be deprecated in favour of using `Runnable`s. Too many people get seriously confused by this, and it's easy for even an experienced professional to make the mistake from time to time...